# AngularJS-Pass label id as parameter in ng-init

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am doing a project where label name will come from a database. I have to pass **label id** as a parameter and retrieve **label name**. When the page loads the value will get initialized in the label. But the problem is the value sets when I use `ng-click`. But I want this using `ng-init`/`ng-bind`, because clicking on the label is not a solution.

**Here is the code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script> 
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(e){
    $scope.label=e.target.id;
    }
   });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<label id="lblID" style="border:10px solid red;" ng-click="test($event)">{{label}}</label>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle DOM manipulation in a directive as below.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 
   
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function (e) {
        alert(e);
    };
});

app.directive('myDir', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.doSomething(element);
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script> 
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(e){
    $scope.label=e.target.id;
    }
   });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<label  my-dir id="lblID" style="border:10px solid red;" ng-init="test('lblID')">{{label}}</label>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. This works for me. You guys are great. My concept is growing slowly in angularjs with the help of u people like you. Thanks again.